# Is this an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, definition

A friend and I are discussing whether this is an ODE:

$$y'(x)+y(-x)=e^x$$

My friend claims it is not because of the $-x$. IMHO, the differential equation can be written as $F(x,y,y')=0$ with:

$$F=y' +  y\circ (-\mathrm{Id}) -\exp$$

and is an ODE, hence. Could you please confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend is definitely right! If it was an ODE, you will be able to find $F\colon\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $y$ is solution if and only if $F(x,y(x),y'(x))=0$. Which is not the case because of the $y(-x)$.

The function you defined take functions as arguments and not triplets of reals!

Comment: Thanks! Do you agree that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#General_definition_of_an_ODE) is not clear? It says _Given F, a function of $x$, $y$, and derivatives of $y$_, which seems in contradiction with what you say (I mean that a derivative is a function, not a real number).

Comment: I do agree that the link you provided has an unclear definition! However, the definition I gave is backed up by the [French wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89quation_diff%C3%A9rentielle#D.C3.A9finition_g.C3.A9n.C3.A9rale). Besides, the equation you gave is called a *functional equation*.

Comment: Your link raises the ambiguity indeed. That what I thought $F$ was supposed to be, a functional equation :)